# How can i cancel my CountDownTimer outside of my method?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, countdowntimer

Lets assume I have a class like that in the below. Firstly I have a `CountDownTimer` in a public scope but it is null now and I have a `startCountDownTimer` method to start my `CountDownTimer`, in `startCountDownTimer` method  I set my `countdowntimer` but after that I want to cancel the `countdowntimer` when the user clicks back button but you know I created my variable in public scope and its null so when I'm trying to cancel my `CountDownTimer` outside of method I get NullPointerException so how can I cancel my `CountDownTimer`? (I dont want to create all of my `CountDownTimer` in public scope.)

```
 public class test {

     CountDownTimer countdowntimer;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         startCountDownTimer();
     }

     void startCountDowntimer(){

         countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1) {
             @Override
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                minText.setText(formatTimeMinutes(millisUntilFinished));
                secondsText.setText(formatTimeSeconds(millisUntilFinished));            
             }

             @Override
             public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Timer Finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }.start();

     }

     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
         super.onBackPressed();
         countdowntimer.cancel();
     }       
}
```

Comment: Don't beginner-alert us but, *please*, rephrase your problem statement into understandable sentences using some punctuation.

Comment: capitalization, code whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Try tackling this problem with boolean values.

You're getting a NullPointerException when trying to call `countdowntimer.cancel()` and `countdowntimer` isn't initialized. So let's make it so that that line of code can't be executed unless `countdowntimer` is initialized.

Declare a global boolean value after your `countdowntimer` declaration.

`Boolean timerOn = false;`

Now, inside your `startCountdownTimer()` method, right after you start the timer, set the `timerOn` boolean to `true`.

Inside your `onBackPressed()` method, replace your code with this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (timerOn) {
       countdowntimer.cancel();
       timerOn = false;
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the `.cancel` method is only executed when the timerOn boolean is true, which will only happen when the timer is initialized.